# Прилагательное от "кафе"

Tags: словообразование, орфография, фонетика

Недавно встретил слово **кафейный** (от кафе)и в связи с ним возникло два вопроса:
 1. Сохраняет ли в этом слове твёрдость звук [ф]?
 2. Допустимо ли в данном слове написание через "э" (*кафэйный*), что бы не было путаницы с более частотным прилагательным от *кофе*?

Comment: >более частотным  
  
Что сие значит?

Comment: >Характеризующий частоту употребления, появления чего-н. Ч. словарь (содержащий сведения о частоте употребления слов)

Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949-1992.

"Более частотный" означает, чаще встречающийся в речи.

Comment: Чаще встречающийся  - более частый.
Более частотный - это словарь, который "более показывает".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Кафешный можно образовать от кафе, суффикс ШН, по аналогии: кино - киношный (разг.)

Из словаря Ефремовой: купе - купейный, желе - желейный, филе - филейный, шоссе - шоссейный,кофе - кофейный - суффикс ЙН.  Поэтому в принципе можно образовать кафе - кафейный, тогда слово "кафейный" будет отличаться от "кофейный" первой гласной буквой А на письме и твердым произношением звука Э в устной речи. Написание Э никак нельзя объяснить, если в "кафе" пишется Е.

По поводу ненормативности. Мне кажется, этот термин мы должны использовать, если слово имеет два варианта, тогда один из них мы можем считать разговорным, просторечным или ненормативным. А  слово "кафе" не имеет даже одного "приличного"  прилагательного, в то время как потребность в таком слове в языке, по всей вероятности, существует.

Comment: Да, согласна. Я тоже посмотрела, получается, что от "кафе"...

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, что в данном слове твердость [фэ] должна сохраняться, по аналогии с "кафе", но на письме вряд ли отразится. Слово, честно говоря, немного странное. Возможно когда-то и станет нормативным. Поисковик такого слова не знает. В словарях его тоже пока нет.

Зато "поиск" знает слово "кафешный" (в словарях нет). Достоинство этого слова - нет сходства с кофе и его однокоренными, а недостаток - оно от слова "кафешка"

Comment: >Поисковик такого слова не знает.

Значит плохо искали. На "кафейный", Яндекс даёт 679 ответов на запрос в кавычках. В том числе на [словари](http://gallicismes.academic.ru/18227/кафейный).

*Кафешный* конечно распространённей, но в том тексте, где мне попалось *кафейный* смотрелся бы нелепо.

Comment: Ой, правда, плохо! Поисковик предложил "кофейный" и вариант "искать кафейный?". Я  увидела "кофейный" и успокоилась. Проморгала возможность поиска дальше (в ночи сидела). Так что ваша правда, просчиталась...

Comment: Да что там мудрить!

Пусть будет "кафешкин". ;)))

Answer (score 3):

Я знаю только одно употребление слова "кафейный": это "кафейный шахматист".

Answer (score 1):

Правильно, конечно, *кафешный*. Ну хотя бы на уровне разговорности.
Кафейный настолько ненормативно, что его нельзя даже оценивать на правильность. Как ни на пиши — все одно одинаково правильно. Или неправильно.

Существительные типа *драже*, *монпансье*, даже *пальто* продуктивных прилагательных нормативно не имеют. Кофе — единичное исключение.
Но при этом написание «кафЭйный» было бы еще и нарушением общего морфемного (морфологического) принципа русского письма.

Из всех подобных образований вспомнилось разве бланманжовый".

Comment: >Кафейный настолько ненормативно, что его нельзя даже оценивать на правильность.

Словарь с примерами употребления слова [ССЫЛКА ](http://gallicismes.academic.ru/18227/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).

Comment: >Словарь с примерами употребления слова  
  
Это не то слово. Там примеры исторического варианта прилагательного к кофе, которое переносили на ***кофейню*** (или наоборот). Вряд ли под *новообразованным* прилагательным "кафейный" сейчас имеют ввиду то же самое.